# how do I start the registration thread which is in another fragment

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I have an app which has a main activity and two fragments running on top of it, One of the fragment is related to Google Cloud Notification registration and receiving of push notifications from gcm . Now the issue is the first time user launches the app and clicks on the notification fragment then only the process of registration with gcm starts and then he starts receiving the notifications . But I want to automatically start the registration process from the main acitvity without the wating for  switching to notification fragment . How do I achieve this? I tried to make a new function in notification fragment and put all code regarding gcm registration into that function and then I tried calling that function from MainActivity but it gets the null pointer exception .. Please take a look at my code

```
public class NotificationFragment extends Fragment {
    TextView lblMessage;
    private AppPreferences _appPrefs;
    public AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mRegisterTask;
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
    ConnectionDetector cd;
    public static String name;
    public static String email;
    public View rootView;
    public NotificationFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gcm_activity_main, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }       

    @Override
    public void onStart (){
        super.onStart();
        autoRegistrationForNotification();
    }

    public void autoRegistrationForNotification()
    {
           _appPrefs = new AppPreferences(rootView.getContext());
            _appPrefs.setToZero();

            cd = new ConnectionDetector(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

            name = " ";
            email = " ";
            // Make sure the device has the proper dependencies.
            //if(cd.isConnectingToInternet())
            try{
                GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            }catch(Exception e){}
            // Make sure the manifest was properly set - comment out this line
            // while developing the app, then uncomment it when it's ready.
            //if(cd.isConnectingToInternet())
                try{
                GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                }catch(Exception e){}
            lblMessage = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lblMessage);
            lblMessage.setText(_appPrefs.getMessageFromArchive());
            getActivity().getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                    DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));
            // Get GCM registration id
            //if(cd.isConnectingToInternet()){
            final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

            // Check if regid already presents
            if (regId.equals("")) {
                // Registration is not present, register now with GCM
            //  if(cd.isConnectingToInternet())
                try{
                GCMRegistrar.register(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), SENDER_ID);}
                catch(Exception e){}
            } else {
                // Device is already registered on GCM
                //if(cd.isConnectingToInternet())
                if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(getActivity().getApplicationContext())) {
                    // Skips registration.              
                //  Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Already registered with GCM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
                    // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
                    // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.
                    final Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
                    mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                        @Override
                        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                            // Register on our server
                            // On server creates a new user
                        //  if(cd.isConnectingToInternet())

                            try{
                                ServerUtilities.register(context, name, email, regId);}
                            catch(Exception e){}
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                            mRegisterTask = null;
                        }

                    };

                    try{
                //  if(cd.isConnectingToInternet())
                        try{
                        mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);}catch(Exception e){}
                    }catch(Exception e){}   
                }
            }//else ends


    }

    /**
     * Receiving push messages
     * */
    public final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          //  _appPrefs = new AppPreferences(getActivity());
            _appPrefs = new AppPreferences(rootView.getContext());

            String newMessage = "";
            try{
                _appPrefs.incrementNotificationCount();


            newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
            // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
            }catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
            try{
            WakeLocker.acquire(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            }catch(Exception e)
            {

            }

            if(_appPrefs.getMessageFromArchive().length() > 800){
                _appPrefs.saveMessageToArchive(" ");
            }

             Time now = new Time();
                now.setToNow();
                int month = now.month;
                int day = now.monthDay;
                int year = now.year;
                DateFormatSymbols dfs = new DateFormatSymbols();
                String[] months = dfs.getMonths();

            //lblMessage.append("\n"+String.valueOf(day)+" " +months[month - 1] + " "+String.valueOf(year)+"\n"+newMessage.toString());

                try{
                    if(newMessage!=null)
                    {   
                        _appPrefs.saveMessageToArchive(_appPrefs.getMessageFromArchive().toString()+"\n   _____________________    \n"+String.valueOf(day)+" " +months[month - 1] + " "+String.valueOf(year)+"\n"+newMessage.toString());

                        lblMessage.setText(_appPrefs.getMessageFromArchive());
                    }else{}

                    }
                catch(Exception e){}
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "New Message: " + newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try{    
            // Releasing wake lock
            WakeLocker.release();}catch(Exception e){}
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`But I want to automatically start the registration process from the main acitvity without the wating for switching to notification fragment`

If you wish to register to GCM from the main activity, even before the fragment is created, you should move the registration code to `onCreate` method of the activity.